# Linux permissions issue on sftp server

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

Good day!
I have a linux sftp server located in VM. This VM has access to a GlusterFS storage, where sftp directories are located. Sftp works via OpenSSH server and chroots sftpusers group to sftp directories on GlusterFS storage. All worked well... After one moment I had got an issue...
Trying to create user:

```
# useradd -d /mnt/cluster-data/repositories/masters/test-user -G masters,sftpusers -m -s /bin/nologin test-user
```

Checking:

```
# cat /etc/passwd | grep test-user
test-user:x:1029:1032::/mnt/cluster-data/repositories/masters/test-user:/bin/nologin
# cat /etc/group | grep test-user
masters:x:1000:test-user
sftpusers:x:1005:test-user
test-user:x:1032:
```

Doing chown and chmod for home dir by hand:

```
# chown -R test-user:test-user /mnt/cluster-data/repositories/masters/test-user
# chmod -R 770 /mnt/cluster-data/repositories/masters/test-user
```

Checking:

```
# ls -la /mnt/cluster-data/repositories/masters/test-user
итого 16
drwxrwx---  2 test-user test-user 4096 Окт 27  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root      masters   4096 Окт 27  2013 ..
```

Adding another user to test-user's group:

```
# usermod -G test-user -a tarasov-af
# cat /etc/passwd | grep tarasov-af
tarasov-af:x:1028:1006::/mnt/cluster-data/repositories/lecturers/tarasov-af/:/bin/nologin
# cat /etc/group | grep tarasov-af
masters:x:1000:tarasov-af,test-user
sftpusers:x:1005:tarasov-af,test-user
lecturers:x:1006:tarasov-af
specialists:x:1008:tarasov-af
test-user:x:1032:tarasov-af
```

Login as tarasov-af:

```
sftp> cd masters/test-user
sftp> ls
remote readdir("/masters/test-user"): Permission denied
sftp> ls -la ..
drwxr-xr-x   13 0        1000         4096 Oct 26 21:30 .
drwxr-xr-x    6 0        0            4096 Oct  2 15:53 ..
drwxrwx---    2 1029     1032         4096 Oct 26 21:53 test-user
```

I tried to login as tarasov-af into bash (usermod -s /bin/bash tarasov-af):

```
$ id
uid=1028 gid=1006
groups=1000,1005,1006,1008,1032
```

p.s. I guess this issue began after VM disk failed and I've got /etc/passwd and /etc/group broken, I've restored them from backups and all previous accounts works well, I have this issue only with new accounts.

Comment: Not a question for [so]. You'd probably do better posting this on [unix.se]

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason of this issue: user tarasov-af has more than 16 secondary groups, first 15 groups work good, other -- don't work. I've set kernel.ngroups_max = 65535 in sysctl.conf on every computer in cluster (GlusterFS) and on sftp VM but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

This issue goes to glusterfs client, it can't manipulate with more than 15 secondary groups.

```
# glusterfs --version
glusterfs 3.2.7 built on Sep 29 2013 03:28:05
```